# Apache - hosts file point subdomain

Tags: apache, virtualhost, hosts

I have a site I developed locally for a client.  They have an existing live site (at www.livesite.com).  I want to move the developed site to their server, but I want to test it on their server before it's live.

I thought I'd install the site in a sub directory on their server (www.livesite.com/dev), and then using my hosts file, make my browser think it's viewing the final live URL (www.livesite.com).

However, I've tried various combination of things in my hosts file, and I can't seem to get it to work.  The server ip followed by the domain / sub-domain.

I'm running on MAMP on OSX.  Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Your `hosts` file just resolves a domain name to an IP address – but that does not give the server any inclination to serve you content any different from what it would for _every_ other request made, where the IP resolving was done any other way.

Comment: Hm, so is there no way to accomplish this?

Comment: There are many different ways, but apart from simple navigating to `www.livesite.com/dev` directly in your browser none that will do without some configuration on the server side. Maybe the simplest way would be to set up a VirtualHost for a subdomain pointing to the `/dev` directory directly. Or using mod_rewrite or something similar to rewrite the request into that directory based on f.e. a special GET parameter or cookie value you send with every request.